# Reminders in my siri shortcuts to notion task manager integration

Tags: notion-api, sirishortcuts, notion, notion-js

I'm exploring Siri Shortcuts integrations to ease the inputs on my notion databases using the notion API and so far is so good how easy it has become to do it.
However i'm having the problem that in my task manager I can't automate reminders to the tasks added via Siri Shortcuts. I’m also exploring using formula property in notion but not having success.
I'm trying to explore other options like adding @reminder to the body of the tasks created but not having succes.
Maybe you guys can help me with solutions or ideas on how to approach this problem.
Thanks a lot!

I tried using @reminder in a text property and using formula property but still not having success